# Using the .IDB file in IDA

Tags: windows, assembly, ida

I've just received from a friend an .IDB file concerning the PE file that I'd like to disassemble in IDA.
What is this file and how can I load/use it with the .EXE it is linked with, in IDA?

Answer (score 2):

An .IDB file is an IDA database file. Generally speaking, an IDB for a PE contains its disassembled version.
You can open it in IDA (File->Open menu) to see its contents.